# crazy high "Wear_Leveling_Count"

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mac, ssd, proxmox

I use an older (2012) MacMini as a Proxmox server and the smartctl gives me a crazy high wear value. I built it as a proxmox (debian) system 2 months ago and disk activity on grafana is quite low.

How do I interpret these values?

I dont think the SSD has seen so much use. The power-on hours seem ok as I used to keep it always on when I had it as a normal OSX system.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Apple SD/SM/TS...E/F/G SSDs
Device Model:     APPLE SSD SM256E
Serial Number:    S121NYND40XXXX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 043584d30
Firmware Version: CXM09A1Q
User Capacity:    251,000,193,024 bytes [251 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jan 30 21:34:40 2022 GMT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       30337
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       482
169 Unknown_Apple_Attrib    0x0013   253   253   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1529536846080
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   189   189   100    Old_age   Always       -       429519536343
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       426
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   066   037   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 8/63)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

Comment: Raw values are _always_ vendor-specific (or even model-specific).

Comment: There might be more than one piece of information coded into a multibyte value. Without the manufacturers definition you might be lost.

Comment: A 2012 mini wouldn't have native support for an SSD, so TRIM etc would need a 3rd party enabler, such as Disk Sensei. Otherwise, left to its own devices, I think it might pile up old sectors until forced to erase at write, which would mean the drive always thinks it's 'full'. [I'm not really sure how it all works, but my own older Macs don't like not having TRIM enabled, it makes them very sluggish, especially on small drives]

Comment: @Tetsujin Can you point me to some RTFM or example? This is a MacMini Late 2012 (i7) with the 256SSD from Apple. The maxed out model had this option.

Comment: Ah, sorry - if it was fitted from new that's fine, it's 3rd party that aren't supported. I've a whole slew of Macs here which were retrofitted. I'd forgotten that mini had an SSD option.